# Logging and limiting SSH connection with a default drop policy

Tags: ssh, iptables

I am having trouble limiting the connection to SSH from a unique ip address. I tried the following rules to restrict an ip address from logging to SSH for more than 3 times in 100 seconds, but it didn't work.

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

-A LOGDROP -m limit --limit 4/minute --limit-burst 3 -j LOG --log-prefix "LOGDROP: " --log-level info
-A LOGDROP -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.12/32 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.12/32 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 100 --hitcount 3 --rttl -j LOGDROP
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.12/32 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The line `-m recent --set` was there, I just missed it out when copy and paste. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
sudo iptables -s 192.168.1.12 -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
sudo iptables -s 192.168.1.12 -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent  --update --seconds 100 --hitcount 3 -j DROP
```

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with my configuration? Your proposal doesn't log the dropped connection.

Answer (score 0):

I figured there is nothing wrong with the configuration. My understanding of SSH connection is flawed. A wrong login password does not cause the SSH connection to be dropped. Hence the hit count limit is not affected until I do a reconnect.